# pandas dataframes resample over uneven periods / minutes

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, average, resampling

searched for it but found no solution - if there is already one sry for asking but i would be thankful for a link

I have a dataframe (df) like this:

```
timestamp          value
2016-03-11 07:37:40 24.6018
2016-03-11 07:37:45 24.6075
2016-03-11 07:37:50 24.599
2016-03-11 07:37:55 24.6047
2016-03-11 07:38:00 24.5905
2016-03-11 07:38:05 24.551
...
```

important start not at a even minute like 07:40:00 but 07:37:40 (could be any time) and i want to resample it - calculate mean values over e.g. 5 minutes labeled with last timestamp of used lines. Desired result with first timestamp 2016-03-11 07:37:40 of raw data :

```
2016-03-11 07:42:40 24.608
2016-03-11 07:47:40 24.605
2016-03-11 07:52:40 24.59
...
```

i tried to use

```
df.resample('5T',how='mean',label='right')
```

and

```
df.resample('300S',how='mean',label='right')
```

with the same result:

```
2016-03-11 07:40:00 24.618
2016-03-11 07:45:00 24.675
2016-03-11 07:50:00 24.599
...
```

it calculates over full minute periods. I found no option to correct this propperly. Saw that "base" could be an option but it seems not very ituitive or nice coded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this I used rolling which will roll over the given frequency and do the mathematical operations like sum,mean etc. In this you need to know the start and end datetime values.

Code:

```
df.timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df.set_index('timestamp',inplace=True)
df = df.rolling('15s').mean()
mask = pd.date_range('2016-03-11 07:37:40','2016-03-11 07:38:05',freq='10S')
df = df.loc[mask]
df

                        value
2016-03-11 07:37:40 24.601800
2016-03-11 07:37:50 24.602767
2016-03-11 07:38:00 24.598067
```

Use your desired window instead of '15s' in rolling as well as date_range that I used.Let me know this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me. I will tkae this but in the meantime i figured out a way to calculate `base` for `resample` if someone needs it:

`base = df.iloc[0].name.minute % 5 + df.iloc[0].name.second`

Comment: @neo You are Welcome. Accept the solution if it worked for you.