# How to resample uneven time stamps per minute

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working on some data where data is recorded every few seconds for an entire day. I have to resample this data by taking the mean for every minute.

For example here is my data

```
Date    Time    Recorded_data
2019-01-01    00:00:20    0.20
2019-01-01    00:00:25    0.25
2019-01-01    00:00:28    0.16
2019-01-01    00:00:32    0.26
2019-01-01    00:00:36    0.28
2019-01-01    00:00:45    0.26
2019-01-01    00:00:48    0.24
2019-01-01    00:00:56    0.24
2019-01-01    00:01:00    0.18
...
```

I want to resample the data above as

```
Date    Time    Recorded_data
2019-01-01    00:00:00    0.23
...
```

I want to take the mean for all data for every minute.

I tried resample with pandas but that just converts all data in the Recorded_data column to `Nan`

this is the code i used to resample the data

```
df.Recorded_data.resample('min').mean()
```

I tried the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432198/pandas-dataframes-resample-over-uneven-periods-minutes), but it does not seem to work

Comment: Are Date and Time two separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Date and Time are separate columns, combine them first and convert to date time. You can then resample on the datetime column,

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])

df.set_index('datetime').resample('H').Recorded_data.mean().reset_index(name = 'Recorded_data')
```

You get

```
    datetime    Recorded_data
0   2019-01-01  0.23
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `T` for minutes with `mean` with parameter `on`, then `DatetimeIndex` is not necesary:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])

df = df.resample('T', on='datetime').Recorded_data.mean().reset_index(name='Recorded_data')
print (df)
             datetime  Recorded_data
0 2019-01-01 00:00:00        0.23625
1 2019-01-01 00:01:00        0.18000
```